# Javascript: Add or Subtract to running total

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript, only a few weeks, and am stuck on something I assume to be simple.  I have searched for hours, but cant find an example to point me in the right direction.  Im basically wanting to create a simple "Running Balance" calculator.  One textbox has the input (added by using add button) and the other textbox has the output.  The output should change depending on what I put into the input textbox and keep adding to the value in the output textbox.

Here is my code in Javascript:

```
var accountBalance = 0;

function addBalance()
{
    var inPrice = document.getElementById("inAmt").value 
    total = parseInt(inPrice += accountBalance);        
    document.getElementById("outBalance").value = total;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
<p>
Enter an amount: 
<input type="text" name="inAmt" id="inAmt" />
</p>
<p>
Display Balance:: 
<input type="text" name="outBalance" id="outBalance" />
</p>
</form>

<p><input type="button" id="addBal" value="Add the amount to the balance" onclick="addBalance()"/></p>
```

I have a feeling my total variable in my function is what I am screwing up.  Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: What are you seeing?

Comment: Here is the actual page I am working with --> http://chrisuchytil.com/wdv221/hw/classhw3.html

The question in reference is near the bottom. If you enter a number into the "Enter an Amount" and then click the Add button below, you can see what it is doing.  Concatenating the accountBalance, instead of adding the the global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part doesn’t really make sense:

```
total = parseInt(inPrice += accountBalance);
```

It takes `accountBalance` (`0`), appends it to `inPrice` (since `inPrice` is a string), stores the value back in `inPrice`, parses the result as an integer, and sets `total` to that integer. What you seem to need is pretty much the reverse, that is:

- Parse `inPrice` so that it’s a number instead of a string
- Add it to `accountBalance` and store the result in `accountBalance`
- Put the new `accountBalance` in `total` (or just use `accountBalance` in the first place)

Or, in JavaScript:

```
var accountBalance = 0;

function addBalance() {
    var inPrice = parseInt(document.getElementById("inAmt").value, 10);
    accountBalance += inPrice;
    document.getElementById("outBalance").value = accountBalance;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I understand now what happened.

Answer (score 1):

You've confused a few variables - the problem was you were never reading the current balance and you were resetting the total variable every time (aside from mixing ints and strings). Here is a version without the total variable:

```
function addBalance()
{
    var inPrice = document.getElementById("inAmt").value 
    accountBalance += parseInt(inPrice, 10);        
    document.getElementById("outBalance").value = accountBalance;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fdureo1s/

Comment: What does the 10 reference or do in the  accountBalance += parseInt(inPrice, 10);    ??

Comment: It's a number base. Base 10 is (usually) the default, but it's always recommended to put it.

Comment: Thank you.  The was the last piece of the puzzle.  It all makes sense now.  Appreciate it!